# Date between other Dates java.time

Tags: java, java-8, java-time

How do you determine if a date is between two other dates with Java 8's `java.time` API?

Comment: What research have you done with the API on the JavaDoc site?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `LocalDate` class has

```
isAfter(LocalDate other)    
isBefore(LocalDate other)   
isEqual(LocalDate other)
```

methods for comparisons with other dates. Here is an example:

```
    LocalDate today = LocalDate.now();
    LocalDate tomorrow = LocalDate.now().plusDays(1);
    LocalDate yesterday = LocalDate.now().minusDays(1);

    if(today.isAfter(yesterday) && today.isBefore(tomorrow))
        System.out.println("Today is... today!");
```